# Getting all files beginning with a specific name and ends with any pattern in glob function (Python)

Tags: python

Please I want to get all files that begins with [a letter]_lehn_[any word or letter] and I wrote this code (Python code in ipython notebook). But it didn't return any file for me. Example of some of my files are "A_lehn_1(23)","4
B_lehn_1(2)copy".

````
import glob

from image_file_name in glob.glob('?_lehn_?.png'):```
````

Answer (score 1):

wildcards should work....

```
import glob
from image_file_name in glob.glob('*'+ '_lehn_' + '*' + '.png'):
```